# Extra white borders on CSS image background in IE6

Tags: html, css, background-image, internet-explorer-6

When this page is viewed in IE6, you will see extra left and right white borders on the button:

http://pastehtml.com/view/1aycieg.html

They don't appear in other browsers (e.g. IE7, IE8, Chrome, Firefox).

I have been trying hard to fix it by changing the margin and padding values of the `<li>` and `<a>` tags but still no success.

I would like to avoid changing the HTML markups if possible.

Anyone got some ideas on this?

Many thanks to you all.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Ie6 does not support png transparency. What should be transparent is white and you are seeing that. 
You could try [pngfix](http://www.twinhelix.com/css/iepngfix/)

Comment: Yeah, you are right. I forgot about this. After converting the images to PNG8 format. It now works even without pngfix.

Comment: Thank you very very much for your hints. It's a very useful one.